# Is it possible to create function to print multiple pyramids besides each other and not below each other?

Tags: c

Im writing the code for printing pyramids.

And wanted to create function that not only takes in the desired height of the pyramids but how many pyramids you want to print.Here i want to make it using recursion.And its relatively easy to do that if you are only interested in printing them below each other.But what if i want to print them to be beside each other aligned horizontally not vertically.

Here is my code and it obviously  cant do that because every pyramid starts below previous one and i cant figure out how to change that is it possible to create such a function?

```
piramida (int n,int broj)
{
    int i=0;
int y=0;
int z=0;
int b=1;
int c=n;
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
     for(z=0;z<c-1;z++)
     {
         printf(" ");
     }
             for(y=0;y<b;y++)
  {
  }
  for(y=0;y<b;y++)
  {
     printf("#");
  }
  printf("  ");
  for(y=0;y<b;y++)
  {
     printf("#");
  }
  printf("\n");
  b++;
  c--;
 }
  
  if(broj>0)
 {
 piramida(n,broj-1);
 }
 
 else printf(" ");
}
int main()
{
    
piramida(9,2);
}
```

Comment: One way would be to create a buffer large enough to hold however many pyramids you want to create and call the function multiple times to fill that buffer in using an offset then print the buffer.

Comment: @RetiredNinja So its impossible with one function like this one that prints below each other? Is that how they do it in actual games then?

Comment: Draw out the desired output. Then analyse each line of output. How many spaces are at the start of a line? How many blocks are needed for the pyramid on that line? Hoe many spaces are needed before the next pyramid? How do these values relate to the line number? Work out a simple mathematical formula, and do the work.

Comment: In a game you'd probably "paint" on a surface of some sort. You can create a 2D array of `char` and treat it as a painting surface and just put the `char`s you want in it at `arr[y][x]`, when done, print it. Every "line" should have a `\n` at the end and the whole array should have a `\0` at the very end.

Comment: Look up "raster scan"...

Comment: If I was making a text based game then the way I mentioned is how I would do it. You build the screen you want to display and then display it. You could do it all in one function if you like, I'd prefer to have a function that draws N pyramids that uses a loop to call some helper functions to handle the details. That is a more flexible approach if I wanted to do something different later.

Answer (score 0):

If you introduced another for loop, that should allow for the adjacent printing of pyramids.  Following is a proof of principle example utilizing your code with an additional level.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void piramida (int n,int broj)
{
    int i=0;
    int y=0;
    int z=0;
    int b=1;
    int c=n;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < broj; j++)    /* Additional loop level */
        {
            for(z=0; z<c-1; z++)
            {
                printf(" ");
            }

            for(y=0; y<b; y++)
            {
            }
            for(y=0; y<b; y++)
            {
                printf("#");
            }
            printf("  ");
            for(y=0; y<b; y++)
            {
                printf("#");
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < (12 - i); k++)
            {
                printf(" ");   /* This prints the needed spacing for each line */
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        b++;
        c--;
    }

    printf(" ");
}
int main()
{
    piramida(9,3);

    return 0;
}
```

The result of testing this was as follows on my terminal.

```
@Una:~/C_Programs/Console/Pyramids/bin/Release$ ./Pyramids 
        #  #                    #  #                    #  #            
       ##  ##                  ##  ##                  ##  ##           
      ###  ###                ###  ###                ###  ###          
     ####  ####              ####  ####              ####  ####         
    #####  #####            #####  #####            #####  #####        
   ######  ######          ######  ######          ######  ######       
  #######  #######        #######  #######        #######  #######      
 ########  ########      ########  ########      ########  ########     
#########  #########    #########  #########    #########  #########
```

Give that a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.